# Broken Internet connection - how to restore to default?

Tags: networking, wireless, vpn, iptables, openvpn

Today after starting my system I was unable to access the Internet. I suspected the VPN client (based on openvpn) I use (that sets up firewall rules to prevent leaks) may be the cause but I restored iptables to the default and it still doesn't work. I have no idea what may be the cause. I think it would be best to restore my networking settings to default, just like fresh after installation - is it possible and if it is, then how can I do it?